# 'wsgen' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, path, cmd, wsgen

well I do seem to be getting this error while trying to create a web service with wsgen. The details in the screenshot[image: wsgen not found]

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: Check the output of `echo %PATH%` in the `CMD` window where `wsgen`fails.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps below

1.Go to control panel

2.Then go to systems

3.In that go to "Advanced System settings"

4.Click on Environment variables

5.In system variables section go to path & Edit that

6.In that at the end at the end put a semicolon & put your jdk bin path.

In my case , i am using jdk 1.7. so i have put the following path in in my environmnet variables path.

my jdk path : **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin"**

*You may need to restart your pc to make it work.*

For more clarification & for a pictorial view visit [this](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/) link.

**Note:** In the above link the jdk path is not mentioned.